# iTween MoveTo and set a new parent at the same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a card game and I want to move the card from parent A to parent B with animation. Initially the parent of the card is parent A. Is it possible to use iTween's MoveTo method to move the card from parent A area to parent B area and set parent B as its parent?

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrHi6.png)

```
public void InitializeCards(int numOfCards) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfCards; i++) {
        GameObject card = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(
            "CardDisplay",
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            Quaternion.identity
        );
        card.transform.SetParent(table.transform, false);
        card.GetPhotonView().RPC("Initialize", RpcTarget.Others, false, null);
        card.GetPhotonView().RPC("Initialize", player, true, null);
        card.transform.SetParent(deck.transform, false);
    }
}
```

In this method I create the card, set its parent to table first, then in the Initialize method I move the card from table area to deck area. At last I set the parent to deck.

```
[PunRPC]
void Initialize(bool isMine, string label) {
    if (label == null) {
        this.card = CreateRandomCard();
        this.label.text = this.card.label;
        this.number.text = this.card.number;
        Debug.Log(this.card.number);
        this.description.text = this.card.desc;
        this.typeText.text = this.card.type;
        this.cardImage.sprite = this.card.cardSprite;
    } else {
        switch (label) {
            case "Attack":
                this.card = new AttackCard();
                break;
            case "Defense":
                this.card = new DefenseCard();
                break;
            case "Heal":
                this.card = new HealCard();
                break;
            case "Take Card":
                this.card = new TakeCard();
                break;
            case "Special Attack":
                this.card = new SpecialAttack();
                break;
            case "Billizard":
                this.card = new BillizardCard();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        this.label.text = this.card.label;
        this.number.text = this.card.number;
        this.description.text = this.card.desc;
        this.typeText.text = this.card.type;
        this.cardImage.sprite = this.card.cardSprite;
    }
    if (isMine) {
        GameManager.GetLocal().numOfcards++;
        iTween.MoveTo(this.gameObject, iTween.Hash("position", new Vector3(-400, -375, 0), "time", 1.5f, "islocal", true));
    } else {
        GameManager.GetRemote().numOfcards++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can just wait for the tween to complete and then set the card's parent to B. Also, I would recommend using a newer/live tweening library, such as DOTween; iTween was great, but it's kinda obsolete now days IMHO

Comment: As Ron said: either do it after or before the movement. You can also simply use a Unity built-in Coroutine for this ...

Comment: @Ron I tried using MoveTo to move the child from A to B. No problem there. But then I set the parent of the card to B, the card moves further down. Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @derHugo The card moves further down (outside of B) when I set the parent of the card to B after it moves from A to B. I set the property "islocal" to true when I move the card, is this property still in effect after I set new parent?

Comment: how do you set the new parent? Could you post your code please?

Comment: @derHugo I posted just now.

Comment: you need to use `SetParent` with the 2nd parameter as true in order to keep the card's position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`SetParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)

optional parameter

> **worldPositionStays**
>     If `true`, the parent-relative position, scale and rotation are modified such that the object keeps the same world space position, rotation and scale as before.

and

> The default value of worldPositionStays argument is true.

```
card.transform.SetParent(deck.transform, false);
```

causes your object to be placed to the new parent **keeping the relative position**.

---

What you rather want is **keep world position** so pass in `true` (or nothing since `true` is the default)

```
card.transform.SetParent(deck.transform);
```

equals

```
card.transform.SetParent(deck.transform, true);
```

equals simply assigning [`Transform.parent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html)

```
card.transform.parent = deck.transform;
```

---

This cleared now look at your method:

```
card.transform.SetParent(table.transform);
card.GetPhotonView().RPC("Initialize", RpcTarget.Others, false, null);
card.GetPhotonView().RPC("Initialize", player, true, null);
card.transform.SetParent(deck.transform);
```

Two issues:

- This runs through without waiting for results so `card.transform.SetParent(deck.transform);` is basically called "immediately" and probably before the tween even started. You could competely skip the `card.transform.SetParent(table.transform);`
- also it doesn't execute this on the other clients only the one executing `InitializeCards`. On all other clients the `card` will keep its original parent (probably `null` = scene root)

You would rather want to do the parenting within the `Initialize` method itself which gets called on all clients and do it as a callback once the `moveTo` is finished or before it starts.